# Search Across Multiple Tables

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter, html-table

I have sports draft results in 4 different tables on 1 single page.  I have a search bar that searches for people's names in the table, and filter to only displays the row they appear in.  Right now it will only search across one table, and not across the other 3.  I am trying to get the search to work universally across any table in my whole page.  I am using tablesaw if any of you are familiar with it.

HTML Table Start:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for Player">
<table class="tablesaw" id="tablesaw" data-tablesaw-mode="swipe" data-tablesaw-minimap>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="persist">Round Value</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="2">1st</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="3">2nd</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="4">3rd</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="5">4th</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="6">5th</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="7">6th</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="8">7th</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="9">8th</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="10">9th</th>
<th scope="col" data-tablesaw-sortable-col data-tablesaw-priority="11">10th</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
                <td class="title">Round 1</td>
                <td width="130"> Mike Trout</td>
                <td width="134"> Giancarlo Stanton</td>
                <td width="148"> Andrew McCutchen</td>
                <td width="151"> Paul Goldschmidt</td>
                <td width="128"> Clayton Kershaw</td>
                <td width="126">Jose   Abreu</td>
                <td width="122"> Adam Jones</td>
                <td width="142"> Anthony Rizzo</td>
                <td width="127"> Miguel Cabrera</td>
                <td width="137"> Yasiel Puig</td>
</tr>
```

And my script:

```
<script>
var $rows = $('#tablesaw tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selector matches elements with tr tags within an element with id tablesaw:

```
var $rows = $('#tablesaw tr');
```

Ids are unique; if you give the same id to multiple elements, all the ids other than the first are invalid. Your selector will only match the first one. If you want to match elements in multiple tables, you should use a classname instead of an id, something like this:

```
var $rows = $('.tablesaw tr');
```

Make sure all your tables have class="tablesaw".

I hope that helps.

Comment: You know I tried this before and it didnt work... I see now I had to change the search selector to a class as well.  Seems to be great now.  Thanks for the help